# How to style the output of an echo to display a grid?

Tags: php, html, css

My team and I have made a database in php my admin for a restaurant, and I'm currently working on the customer dashboard. Im using for each loops to display complete orders in one of the dashboard tabs, and have the code working, but right now it just outputs regular black text. I was wondering how to style it to output the rows as a grid, similar to bootstrap grids.

I've tried to just add containers with rows and columns to the foreach echo itself, but its just not working as I thought it would.

```
<div id="CurrentOrders" class="tabcontent" style="margin-left: 24px">
<!-- This information will be pulled from the Orders table in the DB -->
  <h3>Current Orders</h3>
  <p>
  <div class="container">
  <?php
  foreach ($orderno as $order) {
    $n = $order['OrderNo'];
    $menunamequery = "SELECT * FROM OrderItem WHERE OrderNo = '{$n}'";

    $currentorders = getRows($menunamequery);

    foreach ($currentorders as $currentorder) {

    echo "Order Number -"." ".$currentorder['OrderNo']." , "."Order -"." ".$currentorder['MenuName']." , "."Quantity -"." ".$currentorder['Quantity']."<br>";
          }
        }
  ?> </div>
  </p> 
</div>
```

The expected result is for these rows im outputting to have some sort of grid layout, the actual result is just plaintext currently.

Sorry if this is a bad question, my team and I just learned php this semester and are hoping to continue getting better at it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply you can use the `table - th - tr - td` tags. `table` should be out of the foreach loop. `th` also with the headers (order no, order). Inside the loop, `tr` and `td`.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool to manage DB, it is not a DB itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply output HTML from PHP:

```
echo '<span style="color: red">'.$currentorder['MenuName'].'</span>';
```

However, it is advised that you sanitize your output, so nobody can "create HTML" by putting tags in the database;

```
echo '<span style="color: red">'.htmlspecialchars($currentorder['MenuName']).'</span>';
```

This does exactly what it says; makes HTML entities from special characters. For example, `>` will be printed as `&gt;`, which the browser will safely render as `>`, instead of trying to interpret it as an HTML element closing bracket.

Alternatively, you can simply write HTML directly if you wish, by closing and opening the PHP tags:

```
// PHP Code
?>
<span class="some-class"><?=htmlspecialchars($currentorder['MenuName'])?></span>
<?php
// More PHP Code
```

You may also want to look into templating engines to make it easier for you, although it depends on the project if it's worth it for you to look into that, since there is a little bit of a learning curve to it.

Comment: Thank you, we are currently using the bootstrap template (i dont know if thats what you mean) is there a similar path I cant take with bootstrap or would you advise directly writing the html?

Comment: @Hummus Bootstrap is a HTML/CSS/JS Framework, and not a templating engine. This emans that you would need to write HTML directly, or actually implement a templating engine. [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/intro.html) is a good place to start, if you wish to start using one.